# Swift - when is data actually loaded in TableViewController

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm very much a Swift beginner - am populating a table view from Firebase data.

In the table footer I want to display some calculated totals under the table columns. However when calling `footerCell.configure(priceLines, isPortrait: isPortrait)` the `priceLines` dictionary is still empty.

How to remedy this?

Thanks in advance, André Hartman, Belgium

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase

class ListTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var priceLines = [NSDictionary]()
    var isPortrait = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ListTableViewController.rotated), name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
        loadDataFromFirebase()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return priceLines.count
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("profileCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PriceTableViewCell
        cell.configure(priceLines, row: indexPath.row, isPortrait: isPortrait, source: "intraday")
        return cell
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("HeaderCell") as! CustomHeaderCell
        headerCell.configure(isPortrait)
        return headerCell
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let footerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FooterCell") as! CustomFooterCell
        footerCell.configure(priceLines, isPortrait: isPortrait)
        return footerCell
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 30.0
    }
    override func tableView (tableView:UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section:Int) -> CGFloat
    {
        return 50.0;
    }

    // MARK:- Load data from Firebase
    func loadDataFromFirebase() {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
        refInter.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
            var tempItems = [NSDictionary]()
            for item in snapshot.children {
                let child = item as! FIRDataSnapshot
                let dict = child.value as! NSDictionary
                tempItems.append(dict)
            }
            self.priceLines = tempItems
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
        })
    }
    func rotated()
    {
        let newDisplay = (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation))
        if(newDisplay != isPortrait){
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        isPortrait = newDisplay
    }
}
```

Comment: The data is updated when you call `reloadData()`, but if you rotate the screen before the data is loaded the first time, nothing will happen because the Firebase fetch works asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation [clearly says](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewcontroller) that

> When the table view is about to appear the first time it’s loaded, the
>   table-view controller reloads the table view’s data.

So, it will reload the table automatically somewhere between `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`. Your `priceLines` is empty at this point and will be populated with data only when the closure in the method `loadDataFromFirebase` is fired. I'm not sure when it happens in your case, but as you call implicitly `reloadData` then you should have already `priceLines` nonempty (of course if the results in the closure have some data)